# Upon ajax success, div does not output php result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a div on my main form:

```
<div id="dynamic-content">RESULT</div>
```

after sending data to php file to insert records via ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {"mydata": myjson},
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {

        $('#dynamic-content').html(''); // blank
        $('#dynamic-content').html(data); // load data
    }
});
```

and with a table as result after a mysql insert in php file:

```
<div class="table-responsive"> 
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
  <th>PRODUCT</th>
  <td><?php echo $product; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>PRICE</th>
  <td><?php echo $price; ?></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

nothing appears in the 'dynamic-content' div.
Why?

Comment: What does `test.php` output?

Comment: try `dataType: "html",`

Comment: it works, thanks @Mohamed-Yousef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are echoing HTML you have to have `dataType: "html"` Since you wrote it as "json" the AJAX will search for JSON output which is not present in your `test.php` file Hence, writing `dataType: "html"` will solve your problem